# VBA Excel Dictionary Object Value

Tags: vba, excel, oop, dictionary

I'm trying to set a value of a dictionary as an object, and then pass the key in to get the object back along with its values and set it as a cell value.

I created the object:

```
'Class Module: Player
Public Name As String
Public Position As String
Public WAR As Double
```

And here is the code:

```
Dim Player as New Player
Dim Players As Scripting.Dictionary


For i = 4 To 29
    If Cells(i, 6) > 0 Then
        Player.Name = Cells(i, 1)
        Player.Position = Cells(i, 3)
        Player.WAR = Cells(i, 6)
        If Not Players.Exists(Cells(i, 3).Value) Then Players.Add Cells(i, 3).Value, Player
    End If
  Next i

  BrewersLineup.Activate
  For i = 4 To 11
    Player = Players(Cells(i, 1))
    Range("B" & i).Value = Player.Name
  Next i
```

I get the error

> Object doesn't support this property or method

on

```
Player = Players(Cells(i, 1))
```

However, when I look in the object Player, I can see a "Player" with the value that has the value that is generated for the key represented by:

```
Cells(i, 1)
```

For example: Players("LF") exists with the values for a Name, Position and WAR attribute.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Yes sorry. I will edit it. Player as New Player and Dim Players As Scripting.Dictionary.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon fixed

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Added

Comment: Add the `Set` keyword before `Player`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want a **distinct** *instance* for every `Cells(i, 6) > 0`, so `Set currentPlayer = New Player` **inside the loop** and conditional block.

Declaring `Player As New Player` doesn't do that. First, avoid using a class name as a local variable identifier - if your class has a *predeclared ID* (probably doesn't anyway), you'll be *shadowing* it and you don't want to do that.

`Dim foo As New bar` creates an *auto-instantiated* object: `foo` is essentially indestructible, and VBA "conveniently" re-creates it if you try. In other words, every single iteration of that loop is overwriting the `Player` object properties and adding the very same object reference to the dictionary, under a new key.

So you end up with 25 identical copies of the same object. Here's how you can fix this:

```
Dim currentPlayer As Player
For i = 4 To 29
    If Cells(i, 6) > 0 Then
        Set currentPlayer = New Player
        currentPlayer.Name = Cells(i, 1)
        currentPlayer.Position = Cells(i, 3)
        currentPlayer.WAR = Cells(i, 6)
        If Not Players.Exists(Cells(i, 3).Value) Then Players.Add Cells(i, 3).Value, currentPlayer
    End If
Next i
```

Watch the identifiers there - `Player` is the *class*; `currentPlayer` is the *object*.

So when you do `Player = Players(Cells(i, 1))`, VBA is assuming you know what you're doing and tries its best to accomodate your writing... and failing at it.

Syntactically, it's seeing this - where `Player` is the *default instance* of the class, if there's one:

```
Player.[DefaultMember] = Players(Cells(i, 1)).[DefaultMember]
```

Because there's no default member, it doesn't know what to do, because there's no way to make a *value assignment* with that statement.

What you want is a *reference assignment* - and that's done with the `Set` keyword:

```
For i = 4 To 11
    Set currentPlayer = Players(Cells(i, 1))
    Range("B" & i).Value = currentPlayer.Name
Next i
```

Another problem is that you've got implicit `ActiveSheet` references all over.

```
BrewersLineup.Activate
```

Remove that line. You already have a `Worksheet` object, named `BrewersLineup`. Use it!

```
For i = 4 To 11
    Set currentPlayer = Players(BrewersLineup.Cells(i, 1))
    BrewersLineup.Range("B" & i).Value = currentPlayer.Name
Next i
```

Do the same for the unqualified `Cells` references in the dictionary-populating loop, and your code will start working fine *regardless of what sheet is currently active*.. which will save you countless headaches in the future.

---

You can further read up on [*default members*](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2018/03/15/vba-trap-default-members/) and [hidden `VB_Attribute` stuff](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2018/04/24/factories-parameterized-object-initialization/) on my *Rubberduck News* blog, where you'll also learn about [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com), an open-source VBIDE add-in project I manage, featuring inspections that would have warned you about the auto-instantiated object variable, the implicit `ActiveSheet` references, the missing `Set` keyword, and possibly other potential issues.

Comment: Thanks for helping me through my reference issues.  However, this gives me "run-time error '13': Type mismatch. on the line: Set currentPlayer = Players(BrewersLineup.Cells(i, 1)).

Comment: @obizues verify what's in `BrewersLineup.Cells(i, 1)`. Try `Debug.Print TypeName(BrewersLineup.Cells(i, 1))` before you pull the value, and put a breakpoint (F9) on the `Set currentPlayer` instruction.

Comment: "Range," when I put a watch on the same value it says in the type column: "Variant/Object/Range" if that helps.

Comment: @obizues right. How about `TypeName(BrewersLineup.Cells(i, 1).Value)`?

Comment: "String" - Worked like a charm on the Set after changing that line to Set currentPlayer = Players(BrewersLineup.Cells(i, 1).Value)

Comment: Scratch that, I was calling the wrong value, the correct call is: Set CurrentPlayer = Players(BrewersLineup.Cells(i, 1).Value).  BrewersLineup.Cells(i, 1).Value is still a String though, but now I'm getting a type mismatch again.

Comment: Nevermind, I was looking for a Dictionary value that didn't have the key I was looking for.  It's strange it gave me a type mismatch error though instead of saying it doesn't exist.

Comment: @obizues and now you know why implicit `Range.Value` calls are evil! ;-)